# Shortest path in the Bidirectional Weighted Graph

Tags: math, path, graph-theory

Each node is connected to the other.

Connection from Node1 to Node2 is not the same in the cost as connection from Node2 to Node1.

Given the graph connection Weight.

Is there any effective algorithm to calculate the fastest(lowest cost) path of two nodes?

What's the name of this type of Graph in Math?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any effective algorithm to calculate the fastest(lowest cost)
> path of two nodes?

Dijkstra

> What's the name of this type of Graph in Math?

Directed

> Connection from Node1 to Node2 is not the same in the cost as
> connection from Node2 to Node1.

To handle this, you can construct a directed graph with two edges between every connected pair of vertices, costed according to the direction of travel.